# OSX terminal running slow in git repositories

Tags: git, terminal

I've noticed that whenever I type a command within a local git repository it takes around 7-8 seconds to register keystrokes and another 7-8 seconds to begin running the command. I've checked my logs from other apps like anti-virus software and haven't found anything obscenely large. I use iTerm, but I've also checked that the exact same thing happens when using Terminal.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

If it helps, I'm on OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 6):

Running `git status` and then pushing the few of the new changes seemed to fasten up the response of iterm for me.

Comment: for me doing only `git status` worked but don't know what caused this issue. I've a repo in digitalocean and rsync some files there.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you have something running in your shell prompt which checks and reports the repository's current state. Many shell frameworks will do this (such as oh-my-zsh, or bash-it). They check the state of the repository every time a prompt is displayed.

If you are in a repository that is for some reason very slow to report its status, that might display this behavior. Some possible reasons include:

- The repository is on a storage device (disk, USB stick, NAS) which is experiencing a problem, and is slow to respond.
- The repository is on a network-mounted filesystem which is slow to respond.
- The repository is on a low-performance filesystem mount, such as mounted into a virtual machine.

Comment: I'm using oh-my-zsh, so you're probably right on that part. However, the repository isn't on any of those three cases; it's on the internal SSD. I have about 21 GB left on the drive and the problem occurs even when my current directory is in a blank git repo. I think I only have one other repo on my SSD and it's not very large. Does oh-my-zsh only check the current repo state?

Comment: @joinkss Probably the easiest test is to go into the repository with some other shell (`exec /bin/bash` for instance) so oh-my-zsh prompt isn't being called, and see if `git status`, `git log`, etc are slow. If they are, then that indicates something in the repo is actually slow; otherwise, oh-my-zsh is probably to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't have large directories that are unnecessary  to stay on your git cache. It is a good practice to exclude compilation directory that contain large binaries from version control (directories like bin, obj, etc.). In case you are using nodejs, sometimes node_modules gets extremely large, and it is a good idea to remove it from git.

> git rm --cached -r node_modules

Then dont forget to add those directories to .gitignore